# Run async Method of Blazor Singleton Service

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server App, which has a state `SharedStateService` and (dummy) data `DummyDataService` service.

```cs
public class SharedStateService
{
    public event Action OnChange;
    private ICollection<DummyData> data;

    public ICollection<DummyData> Data
    {
        get => this.data;
        set
        {
            this.data = value;
            this.OnChange?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}

public class DummyDataService
{
    private readonly SharedStateService sharedStateService;
    private readonly TestContext context;

    public CompanyService(TestContext context, SharedStateService sharedStateService)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.sharedStateService = sharedStateService;
    }

    public async Task<bool> AddData(DummyData data)
    {
        try
        {
            await this.context.Set<DummyData>().AddAsync(data);
            await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

        await this.ReloadData();
        return true;
    }

    public async Task ReloadData()
    {
        this.sharedStateService.Data = await this.context.Set<DummyData>().ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

I have the following problem now. I do not know how I can call my `ReloadData` function after the server starts. I can put it into my `App.razor`, but then it gets called initially for each open connection. I don't want that. I want the data to be fetched into the SharedStateService once after the startup and then only when there are changes (data added, removed, edited).

I first tried to put it into the constructor of the `DummyDataService`, but I cannot call async methods in it (except `_ = ReloadData`, which results in an aborted task sometimes). Is my approach wrong altogether or am I missing something? Is it maybe possible to call the method in my `Program.cs`?

Comment: What process loads data into the `SharedStateService` initially?  Who consumes the `SharedStateService`?  And Server or WASM?  There is a simple answer to your problem (there's nothing unique about it), but we can't give you that answer without the full explanation of what you want.  What I can tell you is you can't access a scoped service from a Singleton.

Comment: As stated in my question, it is a Blazor Server App. Regarding your last sentence, the DI works without any problems. You stated my problem in your first sentence. I don't know, where I need to initially run `ReloadData`. At least I have no access in it in my `Program.cs`, where it would make sense. The `SharedStateService` is, as the name suggests, used by any component to have access to the data. Again: This already works.

Answer (score 1):

try run the ReloadData during DI

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton( sp =>
{
    var context = sp.GetRequiredService<TestContext>();
    var sharedStateService = sp.GetRequiredService<SharedStateService>();
    var service = new DummyDataService(context, sharedStateService);
    service.ReloadData();
    return service;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How do I inject a service to the DummyDataService in this case? In this case, service is reliant to the SharedStateService.

Comment: I have edited the answer. You can use the IServiceProvider to instantiate other service.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but this does not work for me. I cannot inject my DummyDataService as a Singleton, since the DbContext (`TestContext`) is Scoped (and should be that way). Therefore, I tried the same method with `builder.Services.AddTransient`. The second and much bigger problem is, that ReloadData is an async method. I tried running it with `_ = service.ReloadData();` and `service.ReloadData().RunSynchronously();`". In both instances, the method is not called for some reason. At least my breakpoint never triggers and logging also does not do anything.

Comment: Did you try service.ReloadData().GetAwaiter().GetResult()?

Comment: I need to further investigate my code, since this leads to an infinite loop somewhere. I try setting up a completely fresh project and try your solution again.

Comment: I got it to work using your approach. BUT: As I said, I need to add my DummyDataService as Scoped or Transient. Singleton is not possible because a DB Context should always be Scoped. This means, everytime I refresh the page or a new Client connects to the server, your code is called again. This does not meet the requirement of only calling the ReloadData-Method a single time on startup.

Comment: What about using IServiceScopeFactory? Inject IServiceScopeFactory in DummyDataService. In the Reload method, create new scope for your DbContext. Same goes to the Add Data method. Not sure if this working, just a flash through

Comment: This sadly does not work, since it should be the other way around. I want, as soon as the `SharedStateService` is created, that the services automatically call a specific method (in my case the refresh method). But your idea got me thinking, that it might be possible to inject the IServiceScopeFactory to create the service there. I need to investigate that a little bit.